# SpriteNode not moving in scene

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am building a game using SpriteKit.
And below is the point where i stucked.

I am placing SKSpriteNode in scene and updating it's location by decrementing it's X Position in

```
- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
```

method.

But when node reaches at X:594, it's stucked there. and not moving afterwords.
I can't get why this happens.

Here is the SKSPriteNode which I am using, with separate class as"BirdNode"

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) SKAction * flap;
@property (strong,nonatomic) SKAction * flapForever;

- (id)initWithImages:(NSArray *)images
{
    if(self = [super init]) {

    NSMutableArray *textures = @[].mutableCopy;
    for (NSString *imageName in images) {
        SKTexture* birdTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:imageName];
        birdTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
        [textures addObject:birdTexture];
    }

    DebugLog(@"Textures = %@",textures);
    self = [BirdNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[textures objectAtIndex:0]];

    self.flap = [SKAction animateWithTextures:textures timePerFrame:0.02];
    self.flapForever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:self.flap];

    [self setTexture:[textures objectAtIndex:0]];

    [self setPhysicsBody:[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.size]];
    [self.physicsBody setCategoryBitMask:obstacleBitMask];
    [self.physicsBody setContactTestBitMask:playerBitMask];
    [self.physicsBody setDynamic:YES];

    [self runAction:self.flapForever withKey:@"flapForever"];
    return self;
}

+ (NSArray *)birdImages:(int)number {
    NSMutableArray *birds = @[].mutableCopy;
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i ++) {
        NSString *birdImage = @"";
        birdImage = [birdImage stringByAppendingFormat:@"flying_bird%d",number];
        birdImage = [birdImage stringByAppendingString:(i+1)<10?@"0":@""];
        birdImage = [birdImage stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",i+1];
        [birds addObject:birdImage];
    }
    return birds;
}
```

Adding the above SPriteNode in Scene.

```
BirdNode *bird = [[BirdNode alloc] initWithImages:[BirdNode birdImages:1]];
bird.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
bird.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = obstacleBitMask;
bird.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = playerBitMask;
bird.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
bird.name = @"Bird";
bird.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:bird.size];
bird.position = CGPointMake(1000, 240);

[self addChild:bird];
[Nodes addObject:bird];
```

And this is the method where I update the position of Node.

```
- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    [self updateNodes:currentTime];
}

- (void) updateNodes:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    //Here nbNodes = [Nodes count];
    for(int i = 0; i < nbNodes; i ++) {
        BirdNode *bird = Nodes[i];
        bird.position = CGPointMake(bird.frame.origin.x - 3, bird.frame.origin.y);
    }
}
```

But, a bird stuck when it reaches to the X position 594 from 1000.
Where the hack i am doing wrong.?
how to solve this issue.

Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried logging the position of the nodes in the update method?

Comment: Is there another physicsBody in the scene around x:594? Such as an obstacle?

Comment: Thanks @akashg Yes I have tried logging position of node. And there is no physics body at the same position. and using NSLog i cam to know that BirdNode is not moving from X-Position 594. If I remove the flap and flapForever actions then it works fine. and updates it's location perfectly. So can't understand how to update it's location with flapping.

Comment: Instead of `bird.position = CGPointMake(bird.frame.origin.x - 3, bird.frame.origin.y);` you could try `bird.position = CGPointMake(bird.position.x - 3, bird.position.y);`

Comment: Thanks @akashg, I have also tried with the bird.position.x instead of using bird.frame.origin.x. But still no luck!!!

Comment: You could switch the birds movement to SKAction that repeats forever.  Create a wall where the bird will eventually fly off the screen and remove the bird on contact with this invisible wall.  Should be more efficient than finding every bird in every update and moving them that way.